# Convert Seq[Seq[String,String]] to Map[String,Seq[String]]

Tags: scala

I need to convert this structure

```
val seq = Seq(Seq("a","aa"), Seq("b","bb"), Seq("a", "a2"), Seq("b","b2") )
```

to this Map:

```
val map2 = Map ( "a" -> Seq("aa","a2"), "b" -> Seq("bb","b2") )
```

cannot use `toMap` because it only works with Tuple2 as input. Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first group by the first item of each sub-seq and then map the resulting grouped values to only keep the second element of subsequences:

```
Seq(Seq("a","aa"), Seq("b","bb"), Seq("a", "a2"), Seq("b","b2") )
  .groupBy(_(0)) // Map(b -> List(List(b, bb), List(b, b2)), a -> List(List(a, aa), List(a, a2)))
  .mapValues(_.map(_(1))) // Map(b -> List(bb, b2), a -> List(aa, a2))
```

which returns:

```
Map(b -> List(bb, b2), a -> List(aa, a2))
```

---

Similar: instead of using `_(0)` and `_(1)` you could also use `.groupBy(_.head).mapValues(_.map(_.last))`

---

The `mapValues` part can be made a bit more explicit this way:

```
.mapValues{
  case valueLists => // List(List(b, bb), List(b, b2))
    valueLists.map{
      case List(k, v) => v // List(b, bb) => bb
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I use `.groupBy(_.head).mapValues(_.map(_.last))` will the order of the keys be preserved? It seems that it doesn't.

Comment: As we're producing a `Map`, the order of keys is not conserved as there isn't a notion of order with `Map`.

Comment: Based on this answer, if instead of a `Map` you want `List((a,List(aa, a2)), (b,List(bb, b2)))` (whose keys are ordered as they appeared first), you can add this 2nd step to the produced `unorderedMap`: `Seq(Seq("a","aa"), Seq("b","bb"), Seq("a", "a2"), Seq("b","b2") ).map(_(0)).distinct.map(k => (k, unorderedMap(k)))`. A `foldLeft` type of solution might also work.